# Lost Events With In Memory Recording

Tags: etw

Why do I keep getting lost events although I record into memory buffers?

[image]

That makes no sense to me. How can it happen that no buffers are dropped but single events? I have tracked the issue down to the CLR Rundown session which always looses some events. The problems seems to be that I have a large number of managed processes (ca. 60) which all at the same time try to send their events to ETW.

I can repro this with

```
C>xperf -start ClrRundown -on "Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime":0x118:5+"Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown":0x118:5 -buffersize 512 -minbuffers 512 -maxbuffers 1024 -Buffering

C>xperf -Loggers ClrRundown
Logger Name           : ClrRundown
Logger Id             : 1e
Logger Thread Id      : 0000000000000000
Buffer Size           : 512
Maximum Buffers       : 512
Minimum Buffers       : 512
Number of Buffers     : 512
Free Buffers          : 504
Buffers Written       : 0
Events Lost           : **29**
Log Buffers Lost      : 0
Real Time Buffers Lost: 0
Flush Timer           : 0
Age Limit             : 0
Log File Mode         : Buffered StopOnHybridShutdown IndependentSession
Maximum File Size     : 0
Log Filename          :
Trace Flags           : ".NET Common Language Runtime":0x118:0x5+"Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown":0x118:0x5
```

I do not care about the few lost events but I always get a warning from WPA when opening such a trace. That confuses non regular users of WPA which are afraid that they did something wrong and it blocks loading the trace file. 
Is there a way to prevent loosing events? The only other flag I did find was  -NoPerProcessorBuffering from xperf which did also not help. Increasing the buffersize to 8MB did also not change anything.

If there is no way to record data without lost events is there are cheap and fast way to reset the lost events count of the resulting not merged ETL file?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is way to get rid of these spurious dropped events I have decided to reset the lost event counter of the ETL file directly:

If you call that method you can reset the LostEvents count which is an int:

```
// Lost event offset is taken from _TRACE_LOGFILE_HEADER32/64 which is the same for x64 and x86
const int LostEventOffset = 0x98;

private static void ResetLostEvents(string etlFile)
{
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(etlFile))
    {
        file.Seek(LostEventOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (BinaryWriter overwriter = new BinaryWriter(file))
        {
            overwriter.Write((int)0);
        }
    }
}
```

This was tested on Win7 and 10 x86, x64 which works for all ETL files I have got so far.